# Change 'omniture' to 'adobe-analytics'

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Hoping you guys can help with a tag wiki request here, as I do not have enough rep on SO to perform this action quite yet.

Several years ago, Omniture was purchased by Adobe, and has since completely rebranded the products. The term 'omniture' has not been used by Adobe since shortly after its acquisition, except in very few circumstances.

I'd like to propose the renaming of [omniture](/questions/tagged/omniture) and [site-catalyst](/questions/tagged/site-catalyst) to [adobe-analytics](/questions/tagged/adobe-analytics), leaving [omniture](/questions/tagged/omniture), [site-catalyst](/questions/tagged/site-catalyst) and [sitecatalyst](/questions/tagged/sitecatalyst) as synonyms. Can someone with sufficient reputation provide assistance regarding this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your story seems to check out ;)

They’ve now been merged and synonymized.

Comment: We gotta get your meta rep higher. :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey how do we do that? I think it's the arrow under the number, but I'm not sure.